# Result code is always 0 in email intent Android

Tags: android, email, android-intent

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);                   
String[] recipients = new String[]{"test@sample.com"};  
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipients);                       emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Sending ALL" );
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hi This is the Mail");                   
emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);               
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."),1);
```

I have the above email intent and it works fine and I want to get the result code after sending / discarding the message.so i tried `onActivityResult()` function ,but `resultCode` is always 0.
Sorry about the English and please help me to solve this.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Result value is" + String.valueOf(resultCode), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It always is 0. You cannot know whether email sent/cancelled or whatever.
:(

Comment: yes that is the problem ,posible results can be 0,1,-1
but I am not getting -1 or 1 ....

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue to get something going I made the chooser myself using an AlertDialog and the PackageManager to list the available options and at least catch a cancel there.